# I just started learning SQL .How do I get my year in this code?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am new to MySQL. I wrote this code but seems not correct.

```
select mm.adi, year(sb.tarih) as yil, Count(1) as satisSayisi
from Marka mm,
     SatisBaslik sb,
     Model mo,
     Araba aa,
     SatisSatirları ss 
where mm.markaId = mo.markaId
  and mo.modelId = aa.modelId
  and aa.arabaId = ss.arabaId
  and ss.satısId = sb.satısId  
group by mm.adi, year(sb.tarih)
```

[image]

---

[Here is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5624v.png)

---

**If I write like this giving error**

```
Where mm.markaId=mo.markaId and mo.modelId=aa.modelId 
and aa.arabaId=ss.arabaId and ss.satısId=sb.satısId and tarih='2017
```

I want to know that how can I get my year

Comment: You provided us only one table, we cant help you if you dont show us the structure of all of them

Comment: @RoseTyler I think you need to learn more about MySQL https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: It's not at all clear what OP is attempting to achieve.i.e. "*get my year in this code*" ... we're left guessing what result OP is attempting to achieve. Given the bit about "`and tarih='2017`,  it looks like OP may be wanting to include a predicate (condition) to restrict the rows returned... but that's just a guess. (And the question is confusingly, tagged with both MySQL and SQL Server).

Comment: @RoseTyler In comment section please tell us what u really want to achieve  we will edit your question

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear what result OP is attempting to return. I'm guessing (just a guess) that OP wants to include a predicate (condition) that restricts the rows to a specific year.

Something like this:

```
SELECT mm.adi
     , YEAR(sb.tarih)   AS yil
     , COUNT(1)         AS satisSayisi 
  FROM Marka mm
  JOIN Model mo
    ON mo.markaId = mm.markaId
  JOIN Araba aa
    ON aa.modelId = mo.modelId
  JOIN SatisSatirlari ss
    ON ss.arabaId = aa.arabaId
  JOIN SatisBaslik sb
    ON sb.satisId = ss.satisId

 WHERE sb.tarih >= '2017-01-01'
   AND sb.tarih <  '2018-01-01'

 GROUP
    BY mm.adi
     , YEAR(sb.tarih)
```

But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your FROM clause should just have the table name. `SELECT <your columns> FROM <your table> WHERE <some condition>;`